# How to compute divergence of a metric tensor?

Tags: differential-geometry, general-relativity

I am reading a paper where the author defines the divergence to be
$$\left(\delta_{g} \dot{g}\right)_{\mu}=-\dot{g}_{\mu \kappa;}{}^{\kappa}$$
where $g$ looks like the De Sitter metric,
$$g=(3 / \Lambda) \frac{-d \tau^{2}+h(x, d x)}{\tau^{2}}.$$

I am not sure if I understand what $;$ means in the subscript of $\dot{g}_{\mu \kappa;}{}^{\kappa}.$ Could someone please explain?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a $(0,2)$ tensor $\mathbf{T}$, then $T_{\mu\nu~;\kappa}$ is often used as an abbreviation for $\nabla_{\kappa}T_{\mu\nu}$ which is itself an abbreviation for
$(\nabla T)_{\mu\nu\kappa}$. (See [semicolon derivative](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SemicolonDerivative.html).) Because this covariant derivative of $\mathbf{T}$ transforms as a tensor, it is sensible to raise and lower indices:
$$T_{\mu\nu ~;}{}^\kappa=g^{\lambda\kappa}T_{\mu\nu~;\lambda}$$
And we can of course contract as well:
$$T_{\mu\nu~;}{}^\kappa=g^{\lambda\kappa}T_{\mu\kappa~;\lambda}$$
I suppose in your case $\mathbf{T}=-\dot{\mathbf g}$.